# cannot return new class type after inheritance

Tags: c#, abstract, radix

```
public class abstract animal
{
     // many fields
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public int id {get; set;}
     // method, return self
     public abstract animal getAnimalByID( int _id)
     {
         // databse connection
         //get data from database and return an animal type

         return animal; <-- cannot work, "return this" can work
     }

} 



public class dog : animal
{
     public override dog getAnimalByID( int _id)
     {
          return (dog )base.getAnimalByID( _id);
     }
}
```

I have a abstract base class and get data from database. dog has more fields and functions than animals and I want to return dog data type from database.

problem 1:

**return (dog )base.getAnimalByID( _id);** return access base class error

problem 2:

**(dog)** returns error too

Comment: `abstract` and `base` are two meaningless tags without context. Tag your question with the **language** you are using.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first class's method cannot be declared as **abstract** if i want to use **base** at second class.

The rest works fine after i took away the **abstract**.

Comment: Is this additional explanation to your question or an answer to it? If it's the former, please **edit** your question instead.

Comment: it is an anwer i found, but I'm not sure if it is the best answer.